# Change HTTP routing by server status

Tags: mongodb, http, go, state-machine

I'm building a REST server in Go and using mongoDB as my database (but this question is actually related to any other external resource).

I want my server to start and respond, even if the database is not up yet (not when the database is down after the server started - this is a different issue, much easier one).

So my dao package includes a connection go-routine that receives a boolean channel, and write 'true' to the channel when it successfully connected to the database. If the connection failed, the go-routine will keep trying every X seconds.

When I use this package with another software I wrote, that is a just a command-line program, I'm using select with timeout:

```golang
dbConnected := make(chan bool)
storage.Connect(dbConnected)

timeout := time.After(time.Minute)

select {
case <-dbConnected:
    createReport()

case <-timeout:
    log.Fatalln("Can't connect to the database")
}
```

I want to use the same packge in a server, but I don't want to fail the whole server. Instead, I want to start the server with handler that returns `503 SERVER BUSY`, until the server is connected to the database, and then start serve requests normally. Is there a simple way to implement this logic in go standard library? Using solutions like gorilla is an option, but the server is simple with very few APIs, and gorilla is a bit overkill.

== edited: ==

I know I can use a middleware but I don't know how to do that without sharing data between the main method and the handlers. That why I'm using the channel in the first place.

Comment: Do you want to report 503 to all requests until the db is up? Or just to some selected endpoints?

Comment: Good question. I guess not, I want to be able to response to requests like server-health, version and so on.

Comment: When you call `http.ListenAndServe` you can provide a different handler which can return 503. Once your connection is established, switch to use the `DefaultServeMux` which can server your routes, if you do not want to use a multiplexer. But I believe Middleware is a better way to go

Comment: Thanks  Abhishek. But this is actually my knowledge gap - how can I switch the mux on runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I have something working, but it does based on common data. However, the data is a single boolean, so I guess it's not so dramatic. I would love to get comments for this solution:

In the dao package, I have this Connect method, that return a boolean channel. The private connect go routine, writes 'true' and exit when succeed:

```
func Connect() chan bool {
    connected := make(chan bool)
    go connect(mongoUrl, connected)
    return connected
}
```

I also added the Ping() method to the dao package; it run forever and monitor the database status. It reports the status to a new channel and try to reconnect if needed:

```golang
func Ping() chan bool {
    status := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            if err := session.Ping(); err != nil {
                session.Close()
                status <- false
                <- Connect()
                status <- true
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }()

    return status
}
```

In the main package, I have this simple type:

```golang
type Connected struct {
    isConnected bool
}

// this one is called as go-routine 
func (c *Connected) check(dbConnected chan bool) {
    // first connection, on server boot
    c.isConnected = <- dbConnected

    // monitor the database status
    status := dao.Ping()
    for {
        c.isConnected = <- status
    }
}

// the middleware
func (c *Connected) checkDbHandleFunc(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if !c.isConnected {
            w.Header().Add("Retry-After", "10")
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            w.WriteHeader(503)
            respBody := `{"error":"The server is busy; Try again soon"}`
            w.Write([]byte(respBody))
        } else {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        }
    })
}
```

Middleware usage:

```golang
...
connected := Connected{
    isConnected: false,
}

dbConnected := dao.Connect()
go connected.check(dbConnected)

mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/", mainPage)
mux.HandleFunc("/some-db-required-path/", connected.checkDbHandleFunc(someDbRequiredHandler))
...
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(addr, mux))
...
```

Does it make sense?